# Url Rewrite - Web.config - HTTPS and www

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, web-config

I need to be able to redirect to HTTPS (currently working) AND www (if it's not in the URL already).

If the URL does **NOT** have the `www`, then it works fine. However, when the URL **DOES** have `www`, it redirects and adds an additional `www`, such as `https://www.www.domain.com`

*Note that I do not want to hard code the domain, and would like to use `HTTPHOST` or something equivalent.*

**Current rewrite rules:**

```
    <rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="WWW Rewrite" enabled="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" negate="true" pattern="^www\.([.a-zA-Z0-9]+)$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.{HTTP_HOST}/{R:0}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ended up with this Regex - `^((?!www).)*[a-zA-Z0-9]+$`

I also had to go into IIS and change "Does not match the pattern" to "Matches the pattern"

```
    <rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="WWW Rewrite" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^((?!www).)*[a-zA-Z0-9]+$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.{HTTP_HOST}/{R:0}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
```

Comment: That way you are doing a double redirection with http://hostwithoutwww.com urls, it is better to put the "WWW rewrite" rule before the "Redirect to Https"