# Issues with https:// non-www re-directing to https://www

Tags: http, iis, https, binding

I have a website which has recently moved from http:// to https://

The site is built with MVC hosted on IIS7, and I know I should have 4 bindings in place for this.

the main one:
        https://www.example.com (port:443 - ip address: *)

and 3 others all to 301 re-direct to the above.

```
    http://www.example.com - (port:80 - ip address: * -re-direct works)
    http://example.com - (port:80 - ip address: * -re-direct works)
    https://example.com - (port:443 - ip address: * -re-direct does not work)
```

Trying to troubleshoot why the bottom one is failing with Site could not be reached. server DNS address could not be found.

Below is the code I am using to re-direct http to https

```
            // The base only redirects GET, but we added HEAD as well. This avoids exceptions for bots crawling using HEAD.
            // The other requests will throw an exception to ensure the correct verbs are used. 
            // We fall back to the base method as the mvc exceptions are marked as internal. 

            if (!String.Equals(filterContext.HttpContext.Request.HttpMethod, "GET", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                && !String.Equals(filterContext.HttpContext.Request.HttpMethod, "HEAD", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                base.HandleNonHttpsRequest(filterContext);
            }

            // Redirect to HTTPS version of page
            // We updated this to redirect using 301 (permanent) instead of 302 (temporary).
            string url = "https://" + filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.Host + filterContext.HttpContext.Request.RawUrl;

            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(url, true);
```

Any ideas what is going wrong here with the bottom binding? Trying to set up 4th property on Google Webmaster Search Console and obviously can't due to failing DNS.

Any help at all is greatly appreciated. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the DNS on our domain provider.

Answer (score 0):

It's better do this kind of thing on web-server level rather than in app code.
For IIS, you need to change file *Web.config* by adding a rewrite rules.
I was not able to test it, but you should add something like that:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Redirect to www" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">              
      <match url="*" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="example.com" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.example.com/{R:0}" />
    </rule>

    <rule name="HTTP Redirect to HTTPS" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.example.com/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. Unfortunately, no joy with that either. 

I'm concerned there is something wrong with the bindings or at GoDaddy level. 

I find it strange that 
        http:// non-www to https:// www works fine  
but 
        https:// non-www to https:// www  doesn't.

Even without the re-direct, I can't get traffic to https:// non-www    to work at all :(

Comment: Did you try [response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38883207/url-rewrite-web-config-https-and-www)?